# How can I install Python pip on the 'aarch64/armv8' platform?

Tags: python, pip, arm64, armv8

I have a board which is powered by the Linux kernel. The board is of the *aarch64/armv8* architecture. The board does not have *apt-get*, but it has *easy_install*. I tried to install using *easy_install*, but I got the following error (as root):

```
cd ~
easy3_install pip
```

Output:

```
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

And:

```
cd ~
easy3_install --version
```

Output:

```
setuptools 36.2.7 from /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (Python 3.5)
```

What are ways to install *pip* on this platform?

If it is possible with *easy_install*, what steps should I follow to get rid of this error?

If not, shall I get cross compiled pip binaries for this architecture or is any [Yocto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yocto_Project) build available?

Comment: Does `easy_install pip` work for you ?

Comment: @Andrew_Lvov Yes I tried, But didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If `easy_install pip` doesn’t work, you can try to build the source.

See *[python-pip 23.1.2-1](https://archlinuxarm.org/packages/aarch64/python-pip)* → *Download*.

Comment: I tried accessing source, https://archlinuxarm.org/packages/aarch64/python-pip/files, it shows an error!

Comment: Oh, thats strange. Try to click on "Download", instead of "Source". I guess, the source is inside the tar file.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the binary, and I found the binary is compiled for python3.7, my machine has python3.5. Will it make any difference if I copy these binaries to python3.5?

Comment: You can just try it. If necessary, you have to adjust your python version